# Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file. Model expected 106 layers, found 4 saved layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have this network (from [SimClR](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.05709) paper):

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    base_model.trainable = True
    #inputs = Input((224, 224, 3))
    inputs = Input((224, 224, 3))
    h = base_model(inputs, training=True)
    h = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(h)

    projection_1 = Dense(256)(h)
    projection_1 = Activation("relu")(projection_1)
    projection_2 = Dense(128)(projection_1)
    projection_2 = Activation("relu")(projection_2)
    projection_3 = Dense(50)(projection_2)

    resnet_simclr = Model(inputs, projection_3)
```

thane after training the model, I saved it:

```
resnet_simclr.save_weights(filename)
```

However, after trying to load the weight in ***ResNet50*** like this:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3), name="input_image")
Resmodel  = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_tensor=inputs, weights=weights_path, include_top=False)
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-cb642379c2ae> in <module>()
      3 from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
      4 inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3), name="input_image")
----> 5 Resmodel  = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(input_tensor=inputs, weights=weights_path, include_top=False) # weights="imagenet"
      6 #Resmodel.load_weights(weights_path)
      7 Resmodel.summary()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, model)
    718   if len(layer_names) != len(filtered_layers):
    719     raise ValueError(
--> 720         f'Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file. '
    721         f'Model expected {len(filtered_layers)} layers, found '
    722         f'{len(layer_names)} saved layers.')

ValueError: Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file. Model expected 106 layers, found 4 saved layers.
```

***EDIT***

The issue I'm trying to do transfer learning (down stream) from RestNet50 with have also 3 projection layer to RestNet50 ( part of Unet backbone) but this Rasnet do not have project head like the trained model. I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try Saving the model again

```
resnet_simclr.layers[1].save_weights(filename)
```